# Why can't I run "docker init"? Getting "'init' is not a docker command"

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up my app as a container.  I run `docker init` in my terminal on my Mac, and I get "docker:'init' is not a docker command."

When I run docker --version, I get Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d

I can also confirm that Docker is running.

Comment: I have 24.0.2, so, maybe you need to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to download the ["Docker Desktop" application](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/). After that, you can re-run the command without any errors.

Answer (score 12):

to use `docker init` you need Docker Desktop 4.26.1 and later.

Comment: 4.18 doesn't support come with docker init, 4.26.1 does

Answer (score 0):

You need Docker desktop v4.26.1